# box-shadow property makes menu overlay another div and look bad

Tags: html, css

I have a menu div and below is content div. When I add box-shadow to content div, it will paint over menu div and it doesn't look good. I would like to see box-shadow being painted behind menu div.

Is there way how to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `z-index` you can position the "layering" of your elements:

```
.menu 
{
   z-index:1;
   position: relative;
}

.content
{
   z-index:0;
   position: relative;
}
```